# New line indentation Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, indentation

I am a complete novice in Haskell and have the following question:
I intend to create the function, which puts three Strings on different lines. Here is the code:

```
onThreeLines :: String -> String -> String -> String
onThreeLines a b c = a++"\n"++b++"\n"++c
```

Here is what I run:

```
  onThreeLines "Life" "is" "wonderful"
```

And what I get:

```
 "Life\nis\nwonderful"
```

I have also tried the following character, but it doesn't work as well.

```
"'\n'"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function works. If you’re running this in GHCi or using `print`, you might be confused by the fact that it calls `show` on the result of your computation, which formats a value as a Haskell term for debugging. For strings, that means including quotes and escapes.

`putStrLn (onThreeLines "Life" "is" "wonderful")` should do exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

Executing it like this should make it work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ onThreeLines "hello" "world" "test"
```

Executing the program, I get:

```
$ ./test.hs
hello
world
test
```

The reason you are getting `"Life\nis\nwonderful"` is because the `Show` instance is being used for displaying  which will escape the newline.

```
λ> putStrLn "hello\nworld"
hello
world
λ> print "hello\nworld"
"hello\nworld"
```

Note that `print` uses the `Show` instance for displaying.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your function. "Life\nis\nwonderful" is the resulting String you want. Just remember that if you want the newlines rendered correctly, pass it to a function like `putStrLn`

```
putStrLn (onThreeLines "Life" "is" "wonderful")
```

Also, be sure to check out the `unlines` function which concatenates a list of strings, separating each element with a newline character.